# Visual Studio git version digitally signed by Johannes Schindelin and not Microsoft Corporation

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, digital-signature

I was attempting to use Git that comes with Visual Studio. Client has program executable filtering software checking the digital signature of executables. Microsoft products are white-listed in this software to run without issue, so Visual Studio 2022/2019/etc installed fine.

However, when trying to run a git operation from VS, for example, "git clone a repo" the filtering software detects that git.exe is actually digitally signed by "Johannes Schindelin" and not "Microsoft Corporation" and is blocked from running by our organization.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\20XX\ Community Professional Enterprise
\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe

Getting management to approve non-MS software is a whole process, does anyone see a way around this besides trying to get "Johannes Schindelin" digital signature white-listed?

Comment: Johannes Schindelin is the Git for Windows maintainer, and what you're probably trying to run is some version of Git for Windows.  You're going to need to get the binary allowlisted unless you can magically find a Microsoft-signed version (which is unlikely).

Comment: Yes I agree unlikely in the near term..  Though Microsoft acquired Github, so making a MS signed version hopefully isn't out of the question.

Comment: Since the paid staff who work on Git for Windows work at GitHub, which is a separate legal entity and operates mostly independently, that's actually unlikely.  The official Git LFS binaries, which are likely also included, are signed by a key owned by GitHub, not Microsoft, and that won't be changing.  You might find more success using Windows Subsystem for Linux and the command line, if that's possible on your system, since it won't have signature checking.

Answer (score 0):

Your company whitelisted Microsoft products because they define many industry standards, especially when it comes to security.

The open source version of VS Code is signed **as-is**, as mentioned in the `LICENSE.txt` file in the repository.

There is no way to change this, other than downloading the official build from Microsoft's website. The version found on GitHub is not the official packaging of VS Code, and it is still open source, meaning that anybody can go in there and edit the code, even malicious code.

Prior to an official release, Microsoft will scan the code completely and approve all pending changes.

This is a security feature provided by your organization, so follow it.

Comment: Stating the obvious is not helpful and not an answer to the question in the post.

Comment: I answered the question, there's no way around this restrictions. And I offered a very good explanation why.

Comment: Your assumption is false. After posting I compiled the gitHub source which creates an unsigned installable which isn't blocked.

Comment: **1** My assumption is not false – i didn't make any assumptions **2** Your questions asked about the open source version of VS Code, not the VSCode git repository **3** `git.exe` is prebuilt, so you can't change its signature **4** This post is not a programming question, its a software question **5** I am deleting this post at 8:00 tonight

Comment: "there's no way around this restrictions." that is false. I compiled git from source and it has no signature and I have now copied the one in Visual STUDIO with this new version and it accepted it and ran fine. 

I'm not sure where you got Visual Studio Code that wasn't mentioned in the question and it is clear from that program path that program in question is Visual Studio: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\.

I hope this may help someone else before this question is deleted. Anyways, Viraj, thank you for inspiring me to work harder and find a solution.